# в / на отделении

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно?
На терапевтическом отделении больницы...
В терапевтическом отделении больницы...

- в вопросе про почтовое отделение писали, что предлог "на" употребляется в значении СПЕЦИАЛИЗИРОВАННОГО отделения (на вечернем отделении), а предлог "в" употребляется для ТЕРРИТОРИАЛЬНЫХ отделений (отдельное помещение, филиал)

Терапевтическое отделение больницы - это специализированное или территориальное отделение (филиал)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае оба эти аспекта могут совпадать (т.е. **возможны оба предлога**), но могут и различаться, например, хирургическое отделение больницы может быть размещено в разнесённых помещениях или частями в разных корпусах. Выбор предлога может зависеть от того, какой аспект хотят подчеркнуть: "на отделении", независимо от расположения его помещений, могут действовать особенные для него порядки (гигиена на хирургическом отделении); на вопрос "где найти больного?" можно ответить двояко, причём ответ "в отделении" (в строгом смысле слова) должен бы направить спросившего в единое помещение, где размещено отделение, а ответ "на отделении" может подразумевать, что отделение расположено сложным образом, и при обращении туда ещё понадобится уточнить, где именно можно найти больного. Но *различие незначительное* и не все с ним считаются. Примеры из книги "Предстоит операция (практические рекомендации для пациентов и их родственников)", изд. "Нева", 2003:

> Кто есть кто на хирургическом отделении (название главы)
>
> В хирургическом отделении все врачи заняты в первую очередь
>   лечением...
>
> Образцовый порядок и чистота на отделении сами по себе не возникают,

и т. д. https://books.google.ru/books?id=Cie5fIt7YDAC&hl=ru&pg=PA29&img=1&zoom=3&ots=mWC_8InRRL&sig=ACfU3U1KSQ7w6ai9JwdEzXwtg436f63uig&w=1280

Answer (score 1):

Сочетание "на терапевтическом отделении"  с предлогом НА  обычно используется, если имеют в виду название абстрактной структуры, а не конкретного пространственного предмета. Например, можно учиться  на терапевтическом отделении института или работать  на терапевтическом отделении больницы, можно сказать: на терапевтическом отделении много хороших специалистов.

Если же речь идет о конкретном помещении, то следует использовать предлог В:  больной сейчас находится в терапевтическом отделении больницы.