# Устойчивое выражение в Санкт-Петербурге

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Живём в Санкт-Петербурге и у нас бытует устойчивая фраза в медицинских учреждениях "лежать на отделении", и даже она напечатана на бланках. По нашему глубокому убеждению правильно говорить и писать "лежать в отделении". Разве мы не правы?

Answer (score 1):

Сперва замечу, что устойчивый оборот, используемый в какой-либо местности постоянно, — это диалектизм и в любом случае имеет право на существование.

Что касается конкретно вашего вопроса, то подобный уже на нашем форуме рассматривался, ответ на него — ответ и на ваш. Ссылка **[здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423075/%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)**.

Answer (score -1):

А если рассматривать не "подобный" вопрос, а именно Ваш по существу, то выражение "лежать на отделении" (касаемо медицины) имеет место быть не токмо в Ленинградской области (до сих пор не переименована), а и во многих населенных пунктах былого СССР. Могу привести как минимум два конкретных и далеких от Вас.